# Why does a perfectly-identical repetition of a drawing command given within an earlier loop  produce exactly the same line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

**Question.** Why does the following code produce a line from vertex 0 to vertex 1 which does *not* perfectly coincide with the analogous line drawn earlier (by way of the foreach-loop)?

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\a/\r in {0/0/100,1/72/100,2/144/100,3/216/100,4/288/100}{
      \node (v\n) at (\a:\r pt) []{};
    }
    \foreach \n in {0,1,2,3,4}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro\auxone{Mod(\n,5)};
      \pgfmathsetmacro\auxtwo{Mod(add(\n,1),5)};
      \pgfmathsetmacro\auxthree{Mod(add(\n,2),5)};          
      \draw[opacity=0.5] (v\auxone)--(v\auxtwo);
      \draw[opacity=0.5] (v\auxthree)--(v\auxone);          
    }
    \draw[opacity=0.5] (v0)--(v1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

The offending output is the following:

[image]

**Remarks.**

- My wish is to have the second line from 0 to 1 coincide perfect with the previously drawn one (and hence create a darker hue, because of the superposition of two opacity-0.5-lines).
- I fail to see any reason for the non-congruence of the two lines. (If one mentally substitues the variables \auxone and \auxtwo, then the two drawing-commands in question seem perfectly identical to me, hence can be expected to have exactly the same effect.)
- I tried to exchange the line

  ```
  \draw[opacity=0.5] (v0)--(v1);
  ```

with the line

```
    \draw[opacity=0.5] (v0.center)--(v1.center);
```

producing a slighly different, yet still unexplained and undesirable, result, which I permit myself to also reproduce (in the hope that this might help someone understand the problem):

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you were using `\pgfmathsetmacro`, which adds `.0` at the end of the numbers, which get interpreted as anchors (`.0` is equivalent to `.east` in this case). If you use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead the lines match perfectly, as they should.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\a/\r in {0/0/100,1/72/100,2/144/100,3/216/100,4/288/100}{
      \node (v\n) at (\a:\r pt) []{};
    }
    \foreach \n in {0,1,2,3,4}{
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\auxone{Mod(\n,5)};
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\auxtwo{Mod(add(\n,1),5)};
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\auxthree{Mod(add(\n,2),5)};
      \draw[opacity=0.5] (v\auxtwo)--(v\auxone);
      \draw[opacity=0.5] (v\auxthree)--(v\auxone);          
    }
    \draw[opacity=0.5] (v0)--(v1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to close the gaps, you may want to use `coordinate`s instead of `node`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n/\a/\r in {0/0/100,1/72/100,2/144/100,3/216/100,4/288/100}{
      \coordinate (v\n) at (\a:\r pt);
    }
    \foreach \n in {0,1,2,3,4}{
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\auxone{Mod(\n,5)};
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\auxtwo{Mod(add(\n,1),5)};
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\auxthree{Mod(add(\n,2),5)};
      \draw[opacity=0.5] (v\auxtwo)--(v\auxone);
      \draw[opacity=0.5] (v\auxthree)--(v\auxone);          
    }
    \draw[opacity=0.5] (v0)--(v1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]